# Angular 8 load external npm package

Tags: angular, npm, package, electron

I want to import the dragscroll.js package. I already tried importing it in the index.html like

```
<script src="../node_modules/dragscroll/dragscroll.js"></script>
```

and in the angular.json like

```
"scripts": [
  "./node_modules/dragscroll/dragscroll.js"
]
```

It gives always this error:
*dragscroll.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND*

I use Angular with Electron, if it's matters.

Comment: Remove what you have already. And just add it to your component: `import 'dragscroll'`

Comment: It's not working. The problem is that this package has just one method in js and I have to write a class and attribute in html in order to work.

Comment: https://github.com/jellekralt/angular-drag-scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working now with dragscoll. I just imported it in the angular.json like: "./node_modules/dragscroll/dragscroll.js". I tried like this, but I wrote the html class for wrong div.